# chi sq post hoc analysis

Tags: r, chi-squared-test, post-hoc

I ran a `chisq.test` for `group` (3 levels) and `Age` (3 levels) which came back as significant. I am trying to figure out how to run some post-hoc tests to see where the significance lies. I am not sure if what I did next was correct.

```
data
       Age
group  1    2   3
1     76   89  127
2     149  132 155
3     106  77  61

age_18_39 = smsDatraw$FM_diag_groups ==1
group_age_18_39 = smsDatraw[age_18_39, ]$agegroup==1
describe(group_age_18_39)


group_age_18_39
n=292 missing=860 distinct=2
value       FALSE    TRUE
Frequency   216      76
Proportion  0.74     0.26
```

I have repeated this step for each of the groups and age categories so I essentially have 9 individuals numbers.

```
t.test(group_age_18_39, group_age_18_39_2) #comparing group 1 and 2 for age 18-39
```

I would like to see where the differences lie and I am not sure what to do next. I originally tried a `t.test` but as it is categorical data I am assuming this isn't correct.

I am hoping I am over complicating this and there is a very simple solution, I just can't see.

Thank you so much to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 0):

The $\chi^2$ test is a test of *independence* of factors *group* and *age*. If you reject the null, which you seem to do, then the factors are not independent, which means that knowledge of *at least one factor value, e.g., age=2 or group=1* will help you *at least narrow down* your prediction of the value of the other factor. For instance, such knowledge could be as vague as knowing Factor $Age=1$ means that $p(Group=2)$ is, say, depressed compared to its background frequency. All it takes is *one* such relationship to be predictable for the null to be rejected.

So how do you find which ones seem to matter?

To sort them out, you can calculate $Z(g,a) = \left(N_{obs}(g,a)-N_{exp}(g,a)\right)/se(g,a)$ for all 9 cases, where $se(g,a)= \sqrt{N_{exp}(g,a)}$ is the expected probability under the null hypothesis. Clearly, your most extreme $Z$ values will be your results from the post hoc. Where you cut off your *post hoc* depends on your favorite *post hoc* method: Bonferroni, Scheffe, etc.

Comment: I've updated the result to give the correct standard error $se(g,a)$.